# Powershell view certificate property privatekeyexportable

Tags: powershell, x509certificate

The Powershell command "Export-PFX" and the cert method export() do not function if a cert's private key is not marked exportable. 
I can't find a way to check if a private key is exportable prior to using the export method.
Here's a sample code.

```
Set-Location Cert:\CurrentUser\My
$certs = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object -Property HasPrivateKey -match $true
if($certs.count -eq 0){Get-certificate -template User ldap:}
foreach($c in $certs){
    $j++
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$home\$j.pfx",$c.export('PFX','changeme')
}
```

The last line calls c.export() to print a pfx file with the password changeme.

If the certificate has no private key, the export() method fails. The second line checks for a private key. The third line runs get-certificate if no certs with private keys are found.

If the private key is not marked exportable, the export() method fails. I need a way to check for that. 
I think certs in the cert store have a property PrivateKeyExportable, but I can't find it using Powershell. Is there a way to check this property in Powershell>

Comment: `$c.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.Exportable`